# php - how to find the month names and numbers between two dates?

Tags: php

I need to find the month names and numbers between two dates
    
For the above two variables, how to find out the month numbers, ie) output will goes like this

> aug2016,sep2016,oct2016,nov2016,dec2016,jan2017

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$date1  = '2013-11-15';
$date2  = '2014-02-15';
$output = [];
$time   = strtotime($date1);
$last   = date('M-Y', strtotime($date2));

do {
$month = date('M-Y', $time);
$total = date('t', $time);

$output[] = $month;

$time = strtotime('+1 month', $time);
} while ($month != $last);

echo implode(",", $output);
?>
```

output

```
Nov-2013,Dec-2013,Jan-2014,Feb-2014
```

Comment: yes!, that's i want, thnak u

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<?php 
 $var1 = "2016-08-15";
 $var2 = "2017-01-31";
 $result = '';
 while (date('m', strtotime($var1)) != date('m', strtotime($var2))) {
    $result .= date('MY',(strtotime('next month',strtotime($var1)))).",";   
    $var1 = date('Y-m-d',(strtotime('next month',strtotime($var1))));
 }
 echo trim($result, ",");
?>
```

Output : Sep2016,Oct2016,Nov2016,Dec2016,Jan2017

Comment: Not work if $date1 is equal to $date2 I expect at least 1 month

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but, based on the output you provided, it seems what you really want to do is extract a month name from month number.

See this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.jdmonthname.php

```
$monthName = jdmonthname($month, 0);
```

I think you should be able to take it from there.